# How can I reveal available function names by typing the first letter?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, autocomplete

I want to reveal function lists in MATLAB when I enter a letter. For example when I type 'm', the list of functions which start with 'm' appears in a column (for example `mean`, `max`, `min` etc.). How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: which version of matlab you are using? mostly if you hold Ctrl then click space , list of available functions appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. However, note that it also shows a list of *variables* in the current workspace. You can read more about it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/check-syntax-as-you-type.html#bswj2of-1) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/avoiding-repetitive-typing-with-tab-completion.html), or by running the following command in MATLAB:

```
web(fullfile(docroot, 'matlab/matlab_env/check-syntax-as-you-type.html#bswj2of-1'));
```

This is where the "Tab completion" settings appear in MATLAB 2016b:
[image: Tab completion settings in MATLAB 2016b]